# Breaking from a definition one level up

Tags: ruby, exit, break, abort

In the code below, `break` exits the program totally and returns to irb, while I want to get back to the line where the print statement is.

```
def f1()
  do_something
end

def f2()
  do_something
end

def f1()
  print "I want to get back here."
  while true
    choice = gets.chomp
    if choice == "exit"
      break
    else
      f2()
    end
  end
end
```

How do you break just one level up?

Comment: Your first definition of `f1` does not make sense. You are redefining it immediately.

Comment: Unless you call `f1` somewhere, your code is not doing anything meaningful. It is not clear how `f1` is used. Also, what you claim cannot be reproduced. `break` only breaks from the condition. It does not break the whole program.

Comment: Though unrelated to your question, you could replace `if...else...end` with `break if choice == "exit"; f2()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another loop outside. It may also be simpler to use `loop` than `while true`:

```
def f1()
  loop do
    print "I want to get back here."
    loop do
      choice = gets.chomp
      if choice == "exit"
        break
      else
        f2()
      end
    end
  end
end
```